# Is "I loved it very much that I had to buy it" wrong?

Tags: word-choice

This sentence was on my English test today and the answer states that the sentence below is grammatically wrong but I feel like there is nothing wrong about it.

> I loved it very much that I had to buy it.

Comment: Probably, *I loved it so much that I had to buy it.* is a correct way to phrase it. Or *I loved it very much, I had to buy it.*

Answer (score 1):

"Very much that" is generally considered to be a mistake in that context. Because the phrase is modifying the loving, "so much that..." is an acceptable phrase to fill in. In other circumstances, "such that" is valid (but here it's either awkward or incorrect). And as others have pointed out, the sentence doesn't have to combine the two clauses to show cause and effect (or at all - two sentences would work just fine).

If I were reading the "very much that" sentence, I would regard it as a mistake.

Comment: Anything is possible in Engllish.Nothing is wrong

Comment: @JVL Usually, we put a space after a period to end a sentence (as your comment shows). We consider things to be "wrong" because it's more useful than explaining exactly why violating certain English conventions is inefficient or makes the sentence hard to undertstand.